# Erlang modules cant load

Tags: erlang

I am facing out a problem when I am trying to call some functions from one module A to a module C.

I have two separate .erl files, which are two erlang files, I have some functions in modulo A that would like to see in module C, but it is not working fine.

Maybe someone can help me with this.

Arigatou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about Erlang right? try to correct you Post's title =).

Well it seems that you are not importing the module A into C.
try importing your A module like this:

```html
-import(Module,Functions).
```

and export your functions from module A also.

you can find additional information here:
[enter link description here](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/modules)

Regards. =)

Comment: Hi Erikson, I have added the import declaration in my module.

Comment: Uhmm, but Have you exported the functions that you want to use? -export([function_name/parameters_count]).  i.e: -export([add/2]).

Comment: Oh! You are right, I have added this export and the import and this is working fine!!. Arigato !!

Comment: But observe that it's noted at the link Erickson included that it's discouraged and not often done to import functions. All it does is allow you to use the function without the module name at the call point (e.g., `bar()` rather than `foo:bar()`, which makes the code harder to follow. All you need to do is export the functions in a given module that you want to be visible from another. So in this case, if module `foo` exported `bar` (`-export([bar/0]).`) then it could be called from other modules (if the module name is included).